# Is there an R socket fucntion that can be used to connect to an IPV6Adress:Port?

Tags: r, sockets, serversocket

I could see an R function that can be used to connect to an ipv4 address space but couldn't find any function that can be used to connect to an IPV6 address.

Used the below function to connect to an IPv4 host

> socketConnection(host="10.1.1.4", port=22)
> A connection with
> description "->10.1.1.4:22"
> class       "sockconn"
> mode        "a+"
> text        "text"
> opened      "opened"
> can read    "yes"
> can write   "yes"

Where as when I try the same for IPV6 address it throws the mentioned error

> socketConnection(host="2c00:4d00:4000:73c0:4::f", port=22)
> Error in socketConnection(host = "2c00:4d00:4000:73c0:4::f", port = 22) :
> cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In socketConnection(host = "2c00:4d00:4000:73c0:4::f", port = 22) :
> 2c00:4d00:4000:73c0:4::f cannot be opened

Comment: @SteffenUllrich IPAdress which I have written in the question is not the correct one, updated the ipaddress in the question to a proper one.

Comment: Are you sure that really the address is the problem? Port 22 is usually a reserved port and binding to it by an unprivileged process will fail. And binding to something were a process is already listening on will fail too. I would expect that R has the ability to get more clear error messages than just "does not work".

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have even tried with other ports as well. The response is the same, connection didn't happen.

Comment: Have you tried the common syntax of wrapping an IPv6 address in brackets, i.e. `[2c00:4d00:4000:73c0:4::f]` ? And again, doesn't R have the ability to get a more specific error message?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich even tried with brackets. Could see the same error msg                         > socketConnection(host="[2c00:4d00:4000:73c0:4::f]", port=80)
Error in socketConnection(host = "[2c00:4d00:4000:73c0:4::f]", port = 80) :
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In socketConnection(host = "[2c00:4d00:4000:73c0:4::f]", port = 80) :
  [2c00:4d00:4000:73c0:4::f]:80 cannot be opened

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am a newbie to R language. Don't have much idea on this

Comment: And you are sure that there is actually some server on this IP address and on this port, i.e. have you successfully tried to connect to it with netcat, telnet or similar?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I have verified using telnet. Telnet connection works